# Paramiko ValueError "p must be exactly 1024, 2048, or 3072 bits long"

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko

I am trying to connect SFTP using Python script. I'm unable to connect due to "p error".

```
import paramiko
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect('####.com', username='####', password='###')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls -l')
```

Error:

> ValueError: p must be exactly 1024, 2048, or 3072 bits long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the value of `p` and include calculated `p` in `dsa.py` file and save it.

### how to calculate P:

```
def _check_dsa_parameters(parameters):

    print(parameters.p.bit_length(),"value of p")
    if parameters.p.bit_length() not in [1024, 2048, 3024]:
```

### include p in this list:

```
(if parameters.p.bit_length() not in [1024, 2048, p-value]:)
```

### After modification:

```
def _check_dsa_parameters(parameters):

    if parameters.p.bit_length() not in [1024, 2048, p-value]:
        raise ValueError("p must be exactly 1024, 2048, or 3072 bits long")
```

Post to rectification it worked Fine.
Thanks